# How can I use parameter like "Lexical Parameter" for Pentaho Reporting

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

How can I use parameter  like "Lexical Parameter" (which is use for Oracle reporting) for Pentaho Reporting.

Here's following is my oracle report query & "AFTERFORM" trigger code
    
    `SELECT FEI.CUSTOMER_NAME
            ,CASE
                 WHEN FEI.OWNBRANCH_CUSTOMER = 0 THEN FEI.LC_NO || '  CTPU'
                 ELSE FEI.LC_NO
             END LC_NUMBER
            ,A.OUTSTANDING
            ,CR_APPR_REF_NO
            ,MARGIN_REALIZED_AMT_CCY
            ,DECODE (SIGN ( MARGIN_BUILD_AMT - MARGIN_SET_AMT)
                      ,'-1', 0
                      , (MARGIN_BUILD_AMT - MARGIN_SET_AMT))
            SHORTFALL
      FROM IMPORT_LC FEI
            ,CURRENCY FEC
            , (SELECT   LOGIN_BRANCH, REFERNCE_NO, ABS ( SUM ( AMOUNT_DR) - SUM ( AMOUNT_CR)) OUTSTANDING
                     FROM TRANSACTIONS
                    WHERE    GLOBAL_TRANS_NO IS NOT NULL
                            AND PRODUCT_CODE    = :P_PRODUCT_CODE
                            AND LOGIN_BRANCH    = NVL ( :P_REPORT_BRANCH, LOGIN_BRANCH)
                            AND TRANS_DATE      <= :P_TRANS_DATE
                            AND GLCODE          = :P_LIAB_ACC
                  HAVING ABS ( SUM ( AMOUNT_DR) - SUM ( AMOUNT_CR)) > 0
                GROUP BY LOGIN_BRANCH, REFERNCE_NO) A
     WHERE    A.LOGIN_BRANCH        = FEI.OWN_BRANCH
             AND A.REFERNCE_NO      = FEI.LC_NO
             AND FEI.IMP_AMEND_NO   =
                      (SELECT MAX ( FF.IMP_AMEND_NO)
                         FROM IMPORT_LC FF
                        WHERE FF.LC_NO = FEI.LC_NO AND FF.OWN_BRANCH = FEI.OWN_BRANCH)
             AND FEI.OWN_BRANCH_CODE    = NVL ( :P_REPORT_BRANCH, FEI.OWN_BRANCH)
             AND FEI.CUSTOMER_CODE      = NVL ( :P_CUST_CODE, FEI.CUSTOMER_CODE)
             AND FEI.IMP_CURR_CODE      = FEC.CUR_CODE
             AND FEI.PRODUCT_CODE       = :P_PRODUCT_CODE
    &P_W`
Where **after parameter form trigger** I set the values of the where clause as:

```
    BEGIN  
      IF  :P_TRANS_DATE < GET_CURRENT_DATE THEN
        :P_W :='';
      ELSE
        :P_W :=' AND  FEI.LC_STATUS   <>6 and  FEI.OPERATION_CODE<>'20' ';
      END IF;

      :P_W:=:P_W||CASE WHEN :P_OTHER_BRANCH=1 
                    THEN ' AND FEI.OWN_BRANCH=FEI.CUSTOMER_BRANCH ' 
              ELSE' AND FEI.OWN_BRANCH<>FEI.CUSTOMER_BRANCH ' 
              END;  
    END;
```

I want to deploy this query in **Pantaho** but as a beginner in **Pantaho** how can I implement Lexical parameter portion in  it...

Comment: I do not know Oracle reporting. What is Lexical Parameter? The language?

Comment: @AlainD
  _Lexical parameters can be used on reports only to build report queries dynamically,when you want the parameter to substitute multiple values at run time.
It replaces any part of a SELECT statement in the data model,such as column names,FROM clause, WHERE clause, ORDER BY clause. 
To create a lexical reference in a query, prefix the parameter name with an ampersand (&),to get the Clause from the User._
  **eg**
  `select * from em where &p_emp;`
  _and in the after parameter form trigger you can set the values of the where clause as:_
  `p_emp:='emp_name like %:p_emp_name% '`

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use parameters like `${PARAM}`

If you want to include a lexical parameter like this `select 'You chose the number ' || &myparm from dual; -- Oracle`. Then `&myparm` can be added as a variable in Pentaho `VAR1=&myparm` and you can use `${VAR}` whilst sending the query. So the &myparm will be sent to Oracle.

If this is not what you want then you may have to give more details in your question.